How to recover USDT sent on Ethereum network to an Arbitrum One address (Metamask)?
I would really appreciate some help recovering some funds.
I opened my metamask to copy my Ethereum address, but my metamask was set to Arbitrum Network, so I copied my Arbitrum One address instead. I used that address to send USDT from another exchange using Ethereum Network.
In other words, I sent USDT from another exchange using Ethereum network, but I input my Arbitrum One address instead of my ERC-20 address.
PS: I already have Arbitrum One network setup within Metamask, I added USDT but I do not see the funds. Probably because the transaction was done on the Ethereum Network.
Any help please, please?

In theory, you open that account in Metamask, switch to Ethereum mainnet and the assets should become visible.

All EVM compatible chains will use the same algorithms for wallet address creation. If you used the same address just changing the network in your MetaMask would be enough. If you used a different address, changing the network in MetaMask and then also changing to that specific address would be required.
If this doesn't solve your problem, please provide clarity on how you added USDT. If the tx was on Ethereum, did you do this through a bridge?
